# Asp.Net WebApi StreamContent performance for large streams in IIS

Tags: iis, amazon-s3, asp.net-web-api

I've been working on an IIS hosted WebApi service that streams a file down from S3 (via an HttpWebRequest) and returns it from the controller via StreamContent. For larger files, around 50mb, we're seeing high CPU spikes. Here's a snippet of the action,

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(Guid id)
{
    var stream = await GetResponseStreamFromS3(id);

    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = doc.FileName };
    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = streamAndLength.Length;

    return response;
}
```

Digging into the StreamContent the spike seems to occur during a Stream.CopyToAsync call. Any ideas on why it would cause the spike and how to mitigate it?

Comment: There is a a whole lot that could be going on here.  Take a look at this article for some ideas http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/  also, remove the code that sets the contentlength.  That gets done automatically based on whether the input stream CanSeek or not.

Comment: Hm, I've been playing with PushStreamContent a bit, in concert with Stream.CopyTo and a larger buffer the numbers are noticeably better. I wonder if it's the Async support causing so much delay since using a vanilla StreamContent or a PushStreamContent using CopyToAsync gives the same results.

Comment: Have you seen this issues: http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/  I suspect your content is being buffered on the server.

Comment: Yeah, I've been through that article, I have buffering off for uploads and downloads explicitly via an IHostBufferPolicySelector and directly set on the HttpWebRequest. I don't have a single issue with uploading large files, just the download for some reason.